# Is this bug with addon

Tags: add-on

I have downloaded the Smart Join [addon](https://bitbucket.org/aivanis/smart-join/downloads/)

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15Qfw1TvcpFqp9sJ-q2_mDwWZhc11qOhm)

I'm having problem with the add-on for this model. When I click on Separate S Join the model or mesh is deleted. When i click on expand smart join there is a empty cube only no mesh inside. I do not want to Apply smart join. How can I separate my mesh with our without the add-on?

[image]

Comment: Is there a post/documentation that provides a little more info about this addon? The website provided in the repository info links to some Chinese language online lottery.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms i have given the link of addon https://bitbucket.org/aivanis/smart-join/downloads/   and not online lottery link

Comment: I was looking for additional information - I was just pointing out something was weird with the repo owner's site. As it stands I don't have much info on how the addon is supposed to function exactly, which makes it hard to determine the root cause. "Separate S Join" is not an entirely self-explanatory name. What source did you use to determine what this addon will do? Perhaps what is happening is expected behavior? Without basic documentation, its hard to find out of its user error, what the user error is, or if the addon is not doing what it should.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms this is an video which can help how the addon works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaPPLJigrgY

Comment: Thank you, I think this is more answerable now.